# Process for creating .Exe file for windows service developed in .Net

Tags: .net

I create windowservice application to submit prospects to clients based on ther inputs, But i am not able install this application on Windows7 OS for my testing purpose. Application is developed using VS2008 and I migrated it VS2010 using conversion tool.

Note: It is having ClassLibrary, in which business logic is implementd.

Can any one help me out in create setup file to install this service into on Windows7 OS.

Regards

Harish kakani.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We need not create any setup project to install windows service.

Just follow below process.

1) Once development is done, build your applicatoin. Then EXE file will be create in bin/Debug folder of your applicatoin.

2) To install a Windows service

1.
On the Start menu or Start Page, open the shortcut menu for Developer Command Prompt, and then choose Run As Administrator.

2.
Navigate to the folder that contains your project's output. For example, under your My Documents folder, navigate to Visual Studio 11\Projects\MyNewService\bin\Debug.

3.
Enter the following command:

installutil.exe MyNewService.exe

4.
If the service installs successfully, installutil.exe will report success.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the service using installutil, at least to get it working.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50614e95(v=vs.71).aspx

Create a folder for your service's .exe and any dependent DLLs, then run installutil on the .exe.

Keep in mind that services by default run with fairly restricted permissions.  If the service is accessing resources like files, ensure that it has adequate permission to do so.